# Antlr4 use TokenStreamRewriter in ParseTreeWalker

Tags: antlr4

Goal :
To replace modify text, which is a rule I defined in .g4 file, that will enter and exit in my listener class in input String
My code :

```
def textModify(input: String) = {  
    val loadLexer = new DSLSQLLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(input))  
    val tokens = new CommonTokenStream(loadLexer)  
    val rewriter = new TokenStreamRewriter(tokens)    
    val parser = new DSLSQLParser(tokens)  
    parser.statement()  
    ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(listener, stat)  
}
```

But how can I call the `rewriter` in my enter function, which can only get the context?
Or can I just rewrite it in `textModify()`? But `rewriter.replace()` requires `index` of token which I can't know when I call it.

I thought it might be easier to show the real situation:
I defined a rule like this:

```
proJob
    : realJob
    ;
realJob
    : job
    ;

job
    : IDENTIFIER
    | quotedIdentifier
    ;

quotedIdentifier
    : BACKQUOTED_IDENTIFIER
    ;
IDENTIFIER
    : (LETTER | DIGIT | '_')+
    ;
BACKQUOTED_IDENTIFIER
    : '`' ( ~'`' | '``' )* '`'
    ;
```

I want to change the text of token when it hits rule `proJob`,for example:
The input : `I am a teacher.`, will enter rule proJob function and I want to modify `teacher` to `teacher_blahblahblah`, how can I manage that

Answer (score 0):

To use the rewriter in your listener methods, you should simply make it an instance variable of your listener. Then the methods will be able to access it.

Comment: still don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

(this is really just an elaboration of @sepp2k's answer)

A `TokenStreamRewriter` is independent of your Listener/Visitor.

note: your example code does not show the creation of the `listener`.  The listener would either have the `TokenStreamRewriter` passed into it, of create a `TokenStreamRewriter` in it's constructor.

In your example, in your `enterProJobContext` method override, you would have access to your `TokenStreamRewriter` because it's a member of your listener.  You can then invoke methods on the rewriter to create a set of changes to be applied to the token stream.  (NOTE: you are NOT modifying the Context object itself.  Take a look at the methods on the `TokenStreamRewriter` class to see what capability it provides for modifying the token stream;)

Once you're done, you would ask the `TokenStreamRewriter` to give you a new String that reflects all the changes you asked for.

so:

```
def textModify(input: String) = {  
    val loadLexer = new DSLSQLLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(input))  
    val tokens = new CommonTokenStream(loadLexer)  
    val rewriter = new TokenStreamRewriter(tokens)    
    val parser = new DSLSQLParser(tokens)  

    val listener = new MyListener(rewriter) // <===

    parser.statement()  
    ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(listener, stat)  

    val revisedSource = listener.rewriter.getText() // <==
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mike

Following your answer i think a good solution is to create a new constructor in your new listen class and from the main program use the new listener with giving him the parameters you want.

in my main program

```
VB6MYListener* Mylistener = new VB6MYListener( &tokens , baseFile, &rewriter , Name );
```

in my new class

```
class VB6MYListener : public VB6ParserListener {

        public:         string FicName;
                        wstring BaseFile;
                        CommonTokenStream* TOK ; 
                        TokenStreamRewriter* Rewriter ; 
                
                            //setter
        public:             // void SetPFile(string Name) { FicName = Name; }
                            //setter
        public:             //  void SetBFile(wstring baseFile) { BaseFile = baseFile; }

                            // void SetINStream(std::fstream infile) { INStream = infile ; }              

                            // Getter 
        public:             string getPFile() { return FicName; }
                            //Getter  
        public:             wstring getBFile(wstring) { return BaseFile; }

      
             // Fonctions pour la traduction avec le listener
     
        /*
        VB6MYListener( wstring baseFile , CommonTokenStream* tok , string Name)
                      {
                        TOK = tok;                        // Flux de tokens
                        BaseFile = baseFile;              // Fichier entree des fichiers en VB6 
                        FicName = Name;                   // Fichier resultat type .pas correspondant au fichier courant traduit
                        }
        */
        
        VB6MYListener( CommonTokenStream* tok , wstring baseFile, TokenStreamRewriter* rewriter , string Name)
        {
            TOK = tok;                  // Flux de tokens
            BaseFile = baseFile;
            Rewriter = rewriter;              
            FicName = Name;             // Fichier entree des fichiers en VB6    // Fichier resultat type .pas correspondant au fichier courant traduit
        }
```

so i can have the visibility on the Token stream and i can use the rewriter in my void functions of the VB6ParserBaseListener.h ( my new class )

i hope that example can help anyone else.